# undefined array key 1 return Carbon::createFromFormat('D M d H:i:s , $matches[1]);

Tags: laravel-8, php-carbon

When i run laravel project using Git Bash

"php artisan serve --host 192.168.1.8 --port 80" Application will run..  but when I access two or three times in link using another PC or android device in same network.. error popup... and cancel automatically

> php artisan serve --host 192.168.1.8 --port 80

> INFO  Server running on [http://192.168.1.8:80].
>
> Press Ctrl+C to stop the server
>
> 2022-11-01 11:33:52 ................................................... ~ 0s
> 2022-11-01 11:33:53 ................................................... ~ 0s
> 2022-11-01 11:33:52 /assets/css/bootstrap.min.css ..................... ~ 1s
> 2022-11-01 11:33:53 ................................................... ~ 0s
> 2022-11-01 11:33:53 /assets/css/now-ui-dashboard.css?v=1.0.1 .......... ~ 0s
> 2022-11-01 11:33:53 /assets/js/core/popper.min.js ..................... ~ 0s
> 2022-11-01 11:33:53 /assets/js/core/bootstrap.min.js .................. ~ 0s
> 2022-11-01 11:33:53 /assets/js/plugins/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.min.js  ~ 0s
> 2022-11-01 11:33:53 /assets/js/core/jquery.min.js ..................... ~ 0s
> 2022-11-01 11:33:53 /assets/js/plugins/bootstrap-notify.js ............ ~ 0s
> 2022-11-01 11:33:53 /assets/js/now-ui-dashboard.js?v=1.0.1 ............ ~ 0s
> 2022-11-01 11:33:53 ................................................... ~ 0s
> 2022-11-01 11:33:53 /assets/js/plugins/chartjs.min.js ................. ~ 0s
> 2022-11-01 11:33:53 /assets/fonts/nucleo-outline.woff2 ................ ~ 0s
> 2022-11-01 11:33:54 /assets/img/favicon.png ........................... ~ 0s
> 2022-11-01 11:34:00 ................................................... ~ 0s
> 2022-11-01 11:34:00 /assets/css/bootstrap.min.css ..................... ~ 1s
> 2022-11-01 11:34:01 ................................................... ~ 0s
> 2022-11-01 11:34:01 ................................................... ~ 0s
> 2022-11-01 11:34:01 /assets/css/now-ui-dashboard.css?v=1.0.1 .......... ~ 0s
> WARN  192.168.1.1.
>
> 2022-11-01 11:34:01
> ErrorException
>
> Undefined array key 1
>
> at C:\xampp2\htdocs\final_laravel\pgrcdata\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand.php:308
> 304▕             : '/^[([^]]+)]/';
> 305▕
> 306▕         preg_match($regex, $line, $matches);
> 307▕
> 308▕         return Carbon::createFromFormat('D M d H:i:s Y', $matches[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKPqc.png));
> 309▕     }
> 310▕
> 311▕     /**
> 312▕      * Get the request port from the given PHP server output.
>
> 1   C:\xampp2\htdocs\final_laravel\pgrcdata\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand.php:308
> Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap{closure}("Undefined array key 1", "C:\xampp2\htdocs\final_laravel\pgrcdata\vendor\laravel\framework\src
> \Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand.php")
>
> 2   C:\xampp2\htdocs\final_laravel\pgrcdata\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand.php:275
> Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand::getDateFromLine("0:45656 Closing")

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKPqc.png)
What can i do.. Please help.. Thank you.

I try to change Carbon Date format but its not working....

Answer (score 0):

Your RegExp should be: `'/^\[([^]]+)]/'` (i.e. the first bracket needs to be escaped) so you captures things in actual bracket and not an range of characters.